# Set the initial Y value of an overflowed div or iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, overflow

Is it possible with javascript or plain html to set the initial y coord, of a div with a scrollbar (overflowed)

I've tried everything under the moon and with anchor tags I've been able to move the whole page to an area but I don't want the browser sidebar to move, just the overflowed div within the page.

Any tips or tricks?

Comment: Your question is not clear, please add sample HTML / CSS information or even better prepare a JSFiddle to show the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a way to do this.

You can use jQuery to set the html/body scrollTop.

Example:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  var yValue = 1000;
  $("html, body").scrollTop(yValue);
}
```